# DJI SDK Android -- move without knowing the destination coordinates

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to develop an application that in one of the steps move the spark programmatically, something as “elevate during 1 second” or “move left during 5 seconds”, or maybe "move one meter to the left" this after pushing one button in the mobile application.

I’m unable to find this kind of functionalities in the API, or code examples.

The more similar functions are:

GoToAction(LocationCoordinate2D coordinate) or 
GoToAction(float altitude)

My question is: This can be done? Or Can I move the spark without knowing the destination coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shy of knowing the coordinates and using waypoints,  you might want to consider virtual joystick.

Using virtual joystick you can move in a small fashion as using the controller,  no destination location need.   However,  the caveat is that you must make movement calculations yourself in order to set the direction,  speed,  e.t.c.

Comment: Ok I´m going to research the following material:  [Virtual Sticks Guide](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-flightController.html#virtual-sticks).  Thanks for the guidance